# Regex remove quotes after and before certain characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to clean a string from unwanted quotes before parsing it to a JSON. The string looks like a general JSON expect sometimes there are some unwanted quotes in the description or other fields e.g.

```
'{"description":"this is a long **"** description with strange quotes **"** like **"**","number":"111111111","quantity":"10","price":"5.20","unit":"ST **"** " }'
```

needs to look like:

```
'{"description":"this is a long description with strange quotes like ","number":"111111111","quantity":"10","price":"5.20","unit":"ST" }'
```

I came up with following regex:

```
[\w\s\d](")[\w\s\d]
```

An issue is that the regex matches also the character before and after the unwanted quote. So with a simple string replace the characters are also getting replace. This is not wanted. It looks like:

```
"{"description":"this is a longescription with strange quotes " like "","number":"111111111","quantity":"10","price":"5.20","unit":"ST"" }"
```

Another issue is, that only the first occurance is matched and not every occurance.

Can someone please help?

**Edit:**
Solved! Correct regex was

```
([\w\s])"(?=\w|(?!\s*[\]}])\s)
```

and with the replace statement:

```
string.replace(/([\w\s])"(?=\w|(?!\s*[\]}])\s)/g, "$1");
```

Comment: Your approach can be expressed as `s.replace(/([\w\s])"(?=[\w\s])/g, '$1')`

Comment: Hello Wiktor, thanks a lot for your response. It almost working perfectly, expect that it does not replace the quote at the end like: "description":"this is a long description with strange quotes  like "". At the end of the description there are still two quotes.

Comment: Try it like this: `s.replace(/:\s*"(.*?)"(?=\s*[\]}])/g, function($0,$1) { return ':"' + $1.replace(/"/g, '') + '"'; })`

Comment: With the regex /([\w\s])"(?=[\w\s"])/g it works fine. The last problem that l have is that at the very end it still matches for the " }. If the quote is folled by a whitespace and }, the quote must not be matched. Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/rBOtY9/1

Comment: Ok, maybe `s.replace(/([\w\s])"(?=\w|(?!\s*[\]}])\s)/g, '$1')`?

Comment: With that regex double " are not matched. https://regex101.com/r/rBOtY9/3

Comment: e.g. "this is a long " description with strange quotes 1"0 like ""  has two " at the end. the second last must also be matched

Comment: That is why I do not like this approach. Try the [full field matching approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827361/regex-remove-quotes-after-and-before-certain-characters?noredirect=1#comment103943827_58827361).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202261/discussion-between-jor-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: I did. However this was the result: 
"{"description":"this is a long description with strange quotes 10 like ,number:111111111,quantity:10,price:5.20,unit:ST " }"
The format of the string should still be '{"asdf":"asdf","asdf1":"asdf2"}'

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Then post it and select as a working answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An issue is that the regex matches also the character before and after the unwanted quote. So with a simple string replace the characters are also getting replace.

Use `'$1$3'` as the replacement string to include the first (character before) and third (character after) capturing groups.

> Another issue is, that only the first occurance is matched and not every occurance.

Use the `/g` regex flag.

Also, note `\d` is redundant as `\w` includes digits.

I'm unsure if `*`'s are actually part of your input or you're just using them to indicate the quotation marks you want removed. I'll assume the latter given your attempted regex and description. Otherwise, just replace `"` with `\**"\**` in the 2nd regex group.

```js
let s = '{"description":"this is a long " description with strange quotes " like "","number":"111111111","quantity":"10","price":"5.20","unit":"ST " " }'

let out = s.replace(/([\w\s"])(")(["\w\s])/g, '$1$3');

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! The * was bad formatting from my part. Sorry :). Your regex is also working fine expect that the if at the end of the descpription the the doulbe quotes are not replaced like "description":"this is a long "description with strange quotes " like "" still gets replaced as "description":"this is a long description with strange quotes  like ""

Comment: Updated to handle the `""`case. @WiktorStribiżew, that doesn't work, you can try it, because `""` won't match `/"[\w\s]/`regardless of whether your groups are capturing or not capturing or just look aheads etc.